# ElasticSearch not mapping JODA time format

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing tweets, and would like to map the created_at field to a date. An example date looks like this:

```
'created_at': 'Wed Sep 21 05:19:16 +0000 2011'
```

which using the JODA time format, I figured out to be:

```
"format" : "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss +SSSS yyyy",
```

However, when trying to index a new tweet I get the following error:

```
{u'status': 400, u'error': u'RemoteTransportException[[Rattler][inet[/192.155.85.243:9301]][index]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Failed to parse [created_at]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [2013-04-30 20:34:43], tried both date format [yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss], and timestamp number]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "2013-04-30 20:34:43" is malformed at "-04-30 20:34:43"]; '}
```

I've tried changing the date format to use

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss +0000 yyyy
```

, and several other variations to just see, and no luck. I'm using the following call to create an initial tweet document:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "created_at" : {"type" : "date", "format" : "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"}
        }
    }
}'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post an example of the record that fails?

Answer (score 10):

The Joda time format you specified is not completely correct.
S is for fraction of second, not timezone as you wanted. Also the "+" sign is included in the timezone parser.

I managed to parse the twitter date format in elasticsearch with this format specifier:

```
"format": "EE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```